# Floating point bug common to different languages?

Tags: c, floating-point

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
          float i,j;
          i=??;
          j=i+1;
          if(i==j)
               printf("Bug");
    }
```

My teacher gave me this qns to find the value of i so that the printf executes.
He said this is a common bug in a lot of languages.

Comment: Make sure to tag homework questions as such please.

Comment: Bug, or just the normal limitations of limited-precision floating point?

Comment: I don't think the down-vote is fair. I don't have specific examples in my pocket, but there are special cases where floating point arithmetic produces unexpected results becuase you're trying to represent an infinity of numbers in a finite number of bits. You won't find the specific answer your teacher is after, but you'll certainly understand the problem: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @user1669251 You have to tell your teacher that it is NOT a bug, but simply (expected) floating point arithmetic. It's a serious mistake calling it a bug.

Comment: @stefan, bug or not all depends on your point of view. It certainly will *look* like a bug the first time you encounter it. And any code that relies on this working as you might naively expect will have a bug.

Comment: Just for completeness: The return type of `main` shall be `int`. Your implementation may provide other types for `main` than `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, but those two are the only types guaranteed to be supported (in hosted implementations) by the standard. Using anything else is unportable at best.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see your point. However it's not a bug even though it seems to be one to many people or it causes non-intended behaviour. Especially it's not a "bug in a lot of languages". Let's call it a feature, agreed? ;-)

Comment: @KeithMiller Please read the description of the homework tag : it is "OBSOLETE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try the boundaries for odd behavior.  This worked for me:

```
#include <float.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float i,j;

    i = FLT_MAX;
    j = i + 1;

    if(i == j)
    {
        printf("they're the same");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked.
Thanks.
But he said that 'i' will have a constant value
I will ask him and update.

Comment: -1: please don't do people's schoolwork for them.

Comment: Ask a good question, I'll try to give a good answer.  The homework tag shouldn't exist IMO